# Is possible to use ${object.method} in jsp with parameters?

Tags: jsp, el

I have an object like this

```
public class Employee {

  public String getName() {
    return "tommaso";
  }

  public String getName(String name) {
    return "tommaso "+name;
  }

}
```

In my action (I use Struts) I set a parameter of object Employee.

```
request.setAttribute("emp",employeeInstance);
```

After that in jsp I write this code

```
${emp.name}
```

and the output is

```
tommaso
```

If I want to use the second method, `public String getName(String name) { ... }`, using same formal text, `${emp. ...something passing a parameter... }`, is possible?

Comment: There's no such method as `setParameter()` on `request`. Please be careful that you don't introduce red herrings in your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you target at least a Servlet 3.0 container like Tomcat 7+, Glassfish 3+, JBoss AS 6+, etc with a `web.xml` conform at least Servlet 3.0 spec, then [EL will let you invoke methods](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/5.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-5.0#invoking-method-expressions) with arguments. Your particular case can then be solved as follows:

```
${emp.getName('foo')}
```

If you aren't on Servlet 3.0 yet or can't upgrade to it, then you'd need to create a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838710/how-do-i-use-static-methods-within-el/9838780#9838780) which takes 2 arguments: the `Employee` and the `name`.

```
public static String getEmployeeName(Employee employee, String name) {
    return employee.getName(name);
}
```

which you then use as follows:

```
${my:getEmployeeName(emp, 'foo')}
```